# No module named django.views.generic error Django 1.6.5

Tags: python, django, view

I installed latest django version (1.6.5). I am using the following

```
from django.views.generic import Listview
```

and `urls.py` is

```
url (r'^',Listview.as_view(queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("date"):10],template_name="info.html"))
```

Comment: Show the complete traceback; not just the error in the title.

Comment: Can you `import django.views.generic` from the Python command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear.. what seems to be the problem?

If the problem is that ListView is not found, then your import for ListView should be

`from django.views.generic.list import ListView`

in Django 1.6.5

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview